# google-earth-stable-7.1.2.2041-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64

Tags: linux, fedora, google-earth

I have downloaded Google earth and am trying to install it on Fedora 19. I am getting the error

> google-earth-stable-7.1.2.2041-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-13.fc19.x86_64

Comment: Not programming related. More suitable for superuser.com.

Comment: I would say that Google Earth is programming related: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/

Comment: Furthermore, Lieuwe's solution is somewhat programming related!

Answer (score 9):

Not quite sure if this needs answering but I guess the question is not closed.

The problem is that the rpm includes the 'install' of /usr/bin/ which is of course nonsense. To fix this do:

- Make sure you have rpmrebuild
- Run (for instance in my case) rpmrebuild -ep /home/geek/Downloads/google-earth-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
- Scroll down and remove line: %dir %attr(0755, root, root) "/usr/bin"
- Save / exit the editor .. after a while you see rpmrebuild exiting saying something like: result: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/google-earth-stable-7.1.2.2041-0.x86_64.rpm
- Install that rpm and your done

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might resolve your problem, but I had the same problem and I find this to fix...

Source:

www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html

10.2.2.2. Conflicting Files

If you attempt to install a package that contains a file which has already been installed by another package, the following is displayed:

> Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
>   file /usr/bin/foo from install of foo-1.0-1 conflicts with file from package bar-2.0.20

To make RPM ignore this error, use the --replacefiles option:

```
 rpm -ivh --replacefiles foo-1.0-1.i386.rpm
```